Given 2 concentric circles, can I find a tangent from a point on the larger circle?
I'm in the process of creating a videogame in which you manage a space station. Spaceships will fly towards the space station to dock with it if the station has what they need and an available docking port. If the ship finds the station unable to fulfill their be needs, the ship should fly past. I need to calculate a route that goes just past the station, to make sure the ship is within the player's view.
I've been trying to figure out how. The question is: If I have 2 concentric circles with the same center, can I calculate a line that tangents the immer circle given only the radiii r and R, and a single point on one or the other circle?
I need an output of all 3 "touch" points on this line. I've spent a few days trying without luck to come up with this without luck so any help is appreciated. First I tried an iterative process but found the results lacking. Then I started thinking about how to calculate the path. I realized I could use the radii of the two circles to form a right triangle. Using the Pythagorean theorem I got the length of the third side.

I realize there are two possible solutions if the given point is a (or c). I don't necessarily need both solutions.
Edit 1: After making this post and reading the comments of ronno, fleablood, and Cyclotomic Field; I got on track and remembered my sin, cos, tan, netting me the angle a, and of course the final angle. I found a way to translate point a along line abc, but found the results lacking. I realized my error in that my method assumes that point a is directly on top of the circle and tried to compensate using
math.atan2(y, x) to rotate the point, but even with that the results were not correct.
My current unsuccessful method of finding b is as follows:
(r = inner radius, R = outer radius, ø = center)

Find the length of the hypotenuse of the triangle abø - Sqrt(r^2 / R^2)
Find the angle offset - atan2(aY, aX)
Find the start angle - atan2(r, R) - angle offset
cX = aX + abc * cos(a)
cY = aY + abc * sin(a)
Leading to the following result (r = 5, R = 10) (using Python to visualize):


I tried multiplying the angle by 90 degrees (Tau) - Which is close, but probably coincidentally so, as it is way off if I change either radii.

Draw lines from $a,b$ and $c$ to the mutual center of each circle. Now figure out how the lengths of the sides of those triangles relate to each other. This will force the points to be at certain places.

Are you allowed to use trig and trig like ideas? If you draw lines from the center to $a$ and from the center to $b$ you get a right triangles with hypotenuse =radius of big circle and adjacent = radius of small circle.

What have you tried in the few days? In what form are you given the point, as a vector from the common center? Calling the center $O$, note that $Oba$ is a right triangle with hypotenuse $Oa = R$ and $Ob = r$.

@Fleablood Not a student, just a forgetful adult :)
Okay so I got the lengths down... And after reading your comments I've got the angles down as well, so given the hypotenuse side is length abc... I suppose I take the original point, shift X by abc* cos(a) and Y by abc*sin(a)? (times 2 to find point c) I'll give it a try...

Well that didn't work, but how could it... The point can be anywhere on the outer circle, but I'm always adjusting by the same angle, so I must need to multiply the angle somehow...

"The point can be anywhere on the outer circle"  well, of course.  There are an infinite number of solutions.  And every point of the inner circle can be a tangent point (and the line will touch the outer circle at precisely two points of the outer circle) and every point of the outer circle can be the "left" endpoint (that touches the inner circle at precisely one tangent point and a specific second point for a "right" endpoint on the outer circle) and every point of the outer circle can be a "right" endpoint. But the cords will all have the same length.

.... so figure out the length of the cord.  ($\frac rR =\sin \theta$ and length $=R\sin \theta$)  and pic a point on the inner circle.  Draw a tangent line and extend it half that length in either direction.

"can I calculate a line "  I guess the first question we all should have asked is just what do you mean by "calculate".  I think you spent days spinning your wheels without realizing:  If you pick any line on the inner circle there is exactly one tangent line.  That tangent line will intersect the outer circle in exactly two points.  So what more do you want?  Do you want to know the length of the chord?  The interior angle of the chord? An x,y formula for the line? A procedure to construct it with a compas and a straightedge.  What?

I want to be able to input any x, y coordinate that I know is on the outer circle, and get the x, y coordinates of the corresponding points b and c.

Yeah so when you're doing these kinds of problems you want to be very careful with your trigonometry. It's tempting to “wing it” and assume that there will be some sign errors in your resulting equation and that you'll just fix those up later by visual comparison, that approach has pretty much never worked for me when programming 2D graphics, there are just too many places where some term can be inserted.
So you're right that there are two solutions, a clockwise or leading solution and a counterclockwise or trailing solution. These depend on the spaceship looking at the space station, one will be at an angle $+\Delta\phi$ and one at angle $-\Delta\phi$. (Greek capital Delta is used to mean "a difference in" or "a change in" something, here I am using it to point out that this is relative to the angle $\phi_0$ that the spaceship would draw between the $x$-axis and the space station itself. So the abolute angles are $\phi=\phi_0 \pm \Delta \phi.$) You are also right that if we take the point of closest approach $P$, this forms a right triangle with the space station and the spaceship. Those are two of the main insights to this problem.
At this point it is best to reduce complexity. Set $r=1$ and put the space station at the origin. You can wrap that function in another function that converts these, much more easily than propagating everything properly through every formula. Then we can start to write $\phi_0 = \operatorname{atan2}(-y, -x)$, while $\Delta\phi$ is one of the angles of the right triangle: the triangle has hypotenuse $h=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},$ opposite side $1$, so we use $\Delta\phi=\operatorname{asin}(1/h)$ to get this angle.
What remains is the third side to that triangle, which is $\ell = h\cos(\Delta\phi).$ This needs to be projected back into coordinates, so you'll finally end up with $(\ell \cos\phi, \ell \sin\phi).$
Here's a quick Python implementation with matplotlib:
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import matplotlib.patches as patch
import math

axes = pp.gca()
axes.add_patch(patch.Circle((0,0), 1, color='lightgray'))
axes.set_aspect('equal')
axes.set_xlim(-5, 5)
axes.set_ylim(-5, 5)

def off_approach(x, y, leading=True):
    """Returns (v_x, v_y) such that at time t=1 the trajectory will kiss the unit circle"""
    hypotenuse = (x**2 + y**2)**0.5
    dphi = math.asin(1.0/hypotenuse)
    phi = math.atan2(-y, -x) + dphi if leading else math.atan2(-y, -x) - dphi
    time_mod = hypotenuse * math.cos(dphi)
    return (time_mod * math.cos(phi), time_mod * math.sin(phi))
    
x = -1.23
y = 2.34
v_x, v_y = off_approach(x, y)

axes.add_patch(patch.Circle((0, 0), (x**2 + y**2)**0.5, color='lightgray', fill=False))
pp.plot([x, x+v_x, x+2*v_x], [y, y+v_y, y+2*v_y], marker='o')

pp.show()



Thank you, this is an amazing solution that fits perfectly with my way of thinking and learning. I think I understand everything you've done, and I love that the radius of the larger circle is implicit from the coordinates! And yes I see how easily I can change the radius of the space station. Thank you so much! and you thank you to everyone else who posted your probably also valid solution - Perhaps this one happened to match my understanding of math :)

Suppose that the common center is $O$. Now note that the tangent $AB$ is perpendicular to the radius $OB$, so $OBA$ is a right triangle, with $OB = r$ and $OA = R$. Therefore $\cos \angle AOB = r/R$, so without loss of generality $\angle AOB = \arccos (r/R) =: \theta$. Now if $OA = R(a_1, a_2)$ and $OB = r(b_1, b_2)$ then $(a_1, a_2)$ is the rotation of $(b_1, b_2)$ by the angle $\theta$.
This gives us $a_1 = b_1 \cos \theta - b_2 \sin \theta$ so $Ra_1 = b_1 r - b_2 \sqrt{R^2 - r^2}$ and $a_2 = b_1 \sin \theta + b_2 \cos \theta$ so $Ra_2 = b_2r + b_1 \sqrt{R^2 - r^2}$. Similarly to get $B$ in terms of $A$ you can rotate $(a_1, a_2)$ by an angle $-\theta$ to get $b_1 = a_1 \cos \theta + b_2 \sin \theta$ and $b_2 = a_2 \cos \theta - a_1 \sin \theta$.

I'm not sure I get your explanation, but it did point me in a direction that I feel is almost right.
ab = hypotenuse, r = inner radius, R = outer radius, ø = center (0, 0), a = the start point on the outer circle, b = tangent point on inner circle, c = end point on outer circle, d is a point on small circle between a and ø, ¤ = inner to outer ratio.
Here's my process, I'm hoping you can tell me where I went wrong.

ab = sqrt(r ^2 + R ^2)
¤ = r / R
angle A = atan(¤)



angle Ø = 1.57079633 - A  5. d = "Lerp" ø towards a by ¤  6. I then rotate d by Ø to get b (The rotation seems to be off here by larger margin depending on how different the radii are, but I believe the method of rotation is correct, as I've tried a few versions... But if this is the actual issue I'll try again.)


Okay.  First we can assume your circles are centered at $(0,0)$.  If your circle is centered at $(a,b)$ we just have to shift them.
Now you have a point on the big circle with radius $R$ at  $A=(u,v)$.  Now we can use trig to write $A = (u,v) = (R\cdot \cos \phi_A, R\cdot \sin \phi_A)$ where $\phi_A$ is the angle from point $A$ to the origin, $(0,0)$ to the $x$-axis.  And we can figure out what $\phi_A$ is by solving $u=R\cos \phi_A$ and $v = R\sin\phi_A$.
Okay.  Now we want to find what points $Q$ on the little circle and $B$ on the big circle are.  We'll assume $Q$ is clockwise of $A$.  Now there is an angle between $A$ then origin and $Q$.  Let's call that angle $\theta$.  Now using trig again so that $Q=(r\cdot \cos \phi_Q, r\cdot \sin \phi_Q)$ where $\phi_Q$ is the angle from $Q$ to the origin to the $x$-axis, we know that $\phi_Q = \phi_A-\theta$.  We just have to figure out what $\theta$ is.
Meanwhile the angle from $Q$ to $C$ has to, by symmetry, also equal $\theta$ and so $C=(R\cdot \cos(\phi_A-2\theta), R\cdot \sin(\phi_A-2\theta)$
So all we have to do is figure out what $\theta$ is.  What is it?
Okay, by symmetry $\theta$ will be the angle for any point on the smaller circle, making a tangent, finding the intersecting point on the big circle.  So let's do this for the simplest case:
Let $(r, 0)$ be a point on the small circle.  It's tangent line is $x=r$.  It lifts straight up vertically and intersects the bigger triangle ant $(r, \omega)$ where, by pythagorean theorem, $r^2 + \omega^2=R^2$ so $\omega=\sqrt{R^2-r^2}$.
So what is $\theta$, the angle between $(r,\omega)$ to $(0,0)$ to $(r,0)$?  Well $\tan \theta = \frac {\omega}{r}= \frac {\sqrt R^2-r^2}{r} = \sqrt{(\frac Rr)^2 - 1}$. and $\theta =\arctan \sqrt{(\frac Rr)^2 -1}$.
And there you have it. If your circles are centered at $(a,b)$ and you have a point $(U,V)$ on the big circle then:
Let $u = U-a, v=V-b$.  Let $\phi_A$ equal equal the values of $\pm \arccos \frac uR$ (positive if $v$ is positive, negative if $v$ is negative), which is also $\pm \arcsin \frac vR$ (positive $u$ is positive and negative if $u$ negative).
Then let $\theta = \arctan \sqrt{(\frac Rr)^2-1}$. (Safe to assume is always positive)
Then your point on the little circle is $(a+ r\cos(\phi_A-\theta), b+ r\sin(\phi_A-\theta))$ and the other point on the big  circle is $(a+R\cos(\phi_A-2\theta), b+ R\sin(\phi_A-\theta))$.
